# The whole UI is suddenly choppy

Tags: 20.04, google-chrome, cpu, gpu, cpu-load

I have been using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS from when it was released and everything was fine until a few days ago. Suddenly UI became choppy (even for small task such as clicking or moving windows). I didn't exactly know why then.

Using `htop`, I saw that CPU is being used for the display (also video playback on Chrome, ff) which I think could be the reason because a single Chrome tab playing a YouTube video sometimes caused all the 4 CPUs to be used at aroung 100%. I have no idea what is going on.